# Check if parameter int is in range of hex?

Tags: c#, .net

I get hex values and need to know if my (parameter that is INT) is in the range of the values.
for example:

```
public bool IsInTheRange(int parameter) {
    string range = "0A-0F";
    return = ????  
}
```

How can I check if the parameter is in the range of 0A-0F ?

Comment: Is the string static, or can it be configured externally? If it is static, you could re-write the function in an obvious way that does not use strings at all...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does the range *really* need to be specified as a string?

```
public bool IsInTheRange(int parameter)
{
    int rangeMin = 0x0A;
    int rangeMax = 0x0F;

    return (parameter >= rangeMin) && (parameter <= rangeMax);
}
```

...and if it does need to be a string then you'll still need to parse that string into min and max bounds:

```
public bool IsInTheRange(int parameter)
{
    string range = "0A-0F";
    string rangeArray = range.Split('-')
                             .Select(x => int.Parse(x, NumberStyles.HexNumber))
                             .ToArray();

    return (parameter >= rangeArray[0]) && (parameter <= rangeArray[1]);
}
```

Comment: Yes it has to because the range actually comes from configuration file.

Answer (score 3):

A little brittle (assumes the range is in a good format, etc):

```
public bool IsInTheRange(int parameter)
{
    string range = "0A-OF";
    int min = int.Parse(range.Split('-')[0], System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
    int max = int.Parse(range.Split('-')[1], System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
    return parameter >= min && parameter <= max;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static bool IsInTheRange(int parameter) 
{
    string range = "0A-0F";
    var tokens = range
        .Split('-')
        .Select(x => int.Parse(x, NumberStyles.HexNumber))
        .ToArray();
    return tokens[0] <= parameter && parameter <= tokens[1];
}
```